# Apache blocking MySQL workbench to connect to my Database

Tags: php, mysql, stack-overflow

I noticed that I can not connect to my Database in MySQL workbench, if I stop apache then only it will connect to the database. This issue is making a second problem If I login to my online website it loads the page forever without any error?

Why is this Happening?

Comment: Is your MySQL configured to only allow one connection? Apache shouldn't effect your mysql workbench, unless apache is overloading your MySQL connections.

Comment: Yes,it is  configured to only allow one connection

Comment: That seems silly now, doesn't it? PHP is going to inherently create threads for each request, and you shouldn't throttle every request trying to go in and connect to the database.

Comment: I fixed the problem, my server did updates and restarted. When it came back online the ports on my server clashed? No idea how it happened,

Comment: after I changed the ports, it started to work